# Clang's ARC support and cycles

Tags: cycle, clang, automatic-ref-counting

Clang has new feature called ARC. Concept looks cool. Is this feature support detecting cycles?

Comment: Reference counting can't handle cycles by definition. (Not an answer because I don't know if it's really reference counting with all its limitations or just something similar with the same name.)

Comment: @delnan You're about right RC cannot handle cycles by definition. But I just want to ensure about it on ARC too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope... ARC is only for automating retain and release - nothing else...  I'm pretty sure Instruments has a tool for this - at least in 4.1/4.2

Comment: There is quite a bit more to ARC than just automatic retain/release, but cycle detection is not a part of it.

Answer (score 2):

ARC has support for weak references. If one of the references in a cycle is a weak reference, this will allow the cycle to be properly released. See [this post](http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2011/Jun/msg00013.html) by Chris Lattner from Apple:

> [ARC introduces] zeroing weak references, which are like assign properties in their cycle breaking ability but a lot safer since they can't dangle.